# CSS: Footer at the bottom of the page overlapping content and with higher width

Tags: css, layout, footer

I would like that the footer stays at the bottom of my web page. I did it, but if the main content is long the user can not scroll the page; the consequence (I guess) is that the footer overlaps the content.
Another problem is that the width of the footer is larger than the "header" of the website.

Here is my CSS for the footer:

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 2em;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 0.2em #4040ff;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-style: solid;}
```

I upload also the image of the screen in order to show you the graphic problem.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me always work this:

```
html { height: 100%; }
body {
    min-height:100%; 
    position:relative; 
    padding-bottom:[footer-height] 
}
.footer { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0 ; right: 0; bottom: 0; 
    height:[footer-height] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written one code snippet, which can solve your problem

```css
  html, body{ 
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
  }
  
  header {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align:center;
  }
  
  footer{ 
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: auto; 
  }
  
  body{ 
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column; 
  }
  
   header p, footer p{
    margin: 5px 0px;
   }

  .container{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <p>This is header</p>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <p>This is body content</p>
</div>

<footer>
<p>This is footer</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```